# a lot of problems with input and def

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, windows

This is my program:

```py
    print("*"*78)
    
    def student_info(name,age,gender):
        print ("Student name : ",name)
        print ("Student age : ",age)
        print("Student gender : ",gender)
    
    sname=input("Enter your name : ")
    sage=input("Enter your age : ")
    sgender=input("Enter your gender : ")
    
    print("*"*78)
    
    print("press '1' to print info '2' for save")
    choice=input("Enter your choice : ")
    if choice=="1":
        print("info:")
        print(student_info(sname,sage,sgender))
    elif choice=="2":
            with open("D:\\Studentinfo.txt","w+") as f:
                f.write(student_info(sname,sage,sgender))
    elif choice!="1" or choice!="2":
            print("command not found!")
    
    print("*"*78)
    input()
```

If I enter 1, then the output is:

```
info:
student name : whatever it is
student age : whatever it is also
student gender : whatever it is
none
```

My problem is with `none` and if I enter 2 it gives me an error.

Also, if I write `f.write(str(student_info(sname,sage,sgender)))` instead of `f.write(student_info(sname,sage,sgender))`, it doesn't give me an error. But if I enter 2 as the choice this is the [console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyjmZ.png) with this [file output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgMUN.png)

Comment: The output has nothing to do with the IDE used to write and run your python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the `student_info` function, the file only contains `None` because if a function doesn´t return something the default behavior is to return `None`. When you are doing `str(student_info(sname,sage,sgender)` you are calling the `__str__` method of the `None` class, that return the string `"None"`. So, the correct way is returning a string, instead of printing inside the function:

```
def student_info(name, age, gender):
    info = f"Student name : {name}\n"
    info += f"Student age : {age}\n"
    info += f"Student gender : {gender}\n"
    return info
```

If you want to print the output of the function, you can do it in your "second choice" in this way:

```
with open("studentinfo.txt", "w+") as f:
    formatted_info = student_info(sname, sage, sgender)
    print(formatted_info)
    f.write(formatted_info)
```

Comment: tysm i really appreciate that <3